# Retrofit 2 - Response body length is -1 on GET requests

Tags: android, request, response, retrofit2

I asked a question some days ago about how can I get the content length of my request and response bodies in my retrofit services. I was able to get the correct content length of my request bodies. But I need the response body of my GET requests and it always returns -1. That's my interceptor below, is anything wrong or there's anything I need to annotate on my GET method to be able to return it's response body length?

```
httpClient.addInterceptor( chain -> {
        okhttp3.Request request = chain.request();
        okhttp3.Response response = chain.proceed(request);
        if(request.body()!=null) {
            long requestLength = request.body().contentLength();
            Log.e("SERVICE", requestLength);
        }
        long responseLength = response.body().contentLength();
        // This response is always -1
        Log.e("SERVICE GENERATOR", responseLength);
        return response;
    });
```